# how to generate webservice map documentation

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, documentation

I am working actually on various java applications, and I am trying to find a way to have a listing of all soap web services exposed by those applications.I am looking to map the web services exposed by its applications.The objective being to document all web services and to have call examples.
For that I am seeking for a maven dependency or an equivalent that can generate automatically a web services map. Did anyone have an idea how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

you can utilize Maven plugins to assist in the documentation process.

One such plugin is the jaxws-maven-plugin, which can be used to generate Java artifacts from a WSDL file. While it doesn't directly generate documentation, it helps in the generation of Java classes that can be annotated with Javadoc comments to describe the SOAP service interface and its operations.